# Array cumulative in one Excel cell

Tags: arrays, dynamic, range, code-coverage, cumulative-sum

Please see attached picture for clarity on the subject.

[Case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGcwp.png)

I have a business case where the requirement is to automatize months of coverage calculation in Column F.

- Column A: Months.
- Column C: Production.
- Column D: Demand.
- Column E: Balance = "Balance N" = "Balance N-1" + "Production N" - "Demand N".
- Column F: Coverage in months (manual inputs as suggested solution).

Requirement is to automatize Column F as shown in picture attached:

- Example 1 for cell "F7" (Blue): cell "E7" (Yellow) = 0 and it covers 0 rows in range "D8:D14" (7 rows Red).
- Example 2 for cell "F8" (Blue): cell "E8" (Yellow) = 10 and it covers 1 row in range "D9:D14" (1 row Green, 5 rows Red).
- Example 3 for cell "F9" (Blue): cell "E9" (Yellow) = 20 and it covers 2 rows in range "D10:D14" (2 rows Green, 3 rows Red).

Conditions:

- No CSE.
- Only Excel 2016 formulas (no 365).
- No helper cells.
- No VBA.

Thank you for support.

We've tried to bring dynamic cumulative calculation of demands in column D as an array into cells F as a part of the final formula, however without any success.

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/